# Как узнать диапазон все каналов в телеграм?

Tags: python, api, search, telethon

Как узнать диапазон все каналов в телеграмм? Может кто знает какие признаки есть в ID(страны, контент, публичная или нет) ? Суть задачи такова мне нужно вычленить все ID новостных каналов желательно русскоязычных и запустить поиск по ключевому слову в нужных ID. Если есть информация где про это можно почитать в документации кидайте ссылку(сам не нашел).

Answer (score 1):

ID выдаётся при регистрации и может быть любым. У меня id 13#767****, у друга 16#771****, следовательно, по id нельзя получить информацию о пользователе. Но можно в ручном режиме, зная интересующий вас канал. https://www.easydoit.ru/telegram/kak-uznat-id-kanala-telegram/